# how can I draw a portion of an ellipse?

Tags: c#, drawing, win-universal-app, ellipse

I am developing a "Universal Windows" project in which I need to draw a portion of an ellipse. In fact I need two types of arcs:

1. a 180° arc going clockwize from point P1 to point P2 where P1 and P2 are both located on the X-axis of the ellipse: this is a half ellipse on one side of the grand axis of the ellipse
2. a 90° arc going clockwize from point P1 to point P2: this is a quarter of an ellipse where P1 is on the X-axis and P2 on the Y-axis (or vice versa)

As `System.Windows.Media.ArcSegment` is not available in this environment, how can I draw these two types of elliptical arcs?

Comment: System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawArc ?

Comment: No: "the type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" and I can not add this reference...

Comment: Use Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ArcSegment

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans. This is the right reference.

Answer (score 0):

[`ArcSegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.arcsegment.aspx) is what you're looking for. Typically you would use `Path.Data` Geometry mini-language in real life applications. Check the syntax [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185585.aspx). The arc part in the Data below starts with the "a".

a *size rotationAngle isLargeArcFlag sweepDirectionFlag endPoint*

```
<Grid>
    <Path
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Fill="Gray"
        Width="202"
        Height="102"
        Stretch="None"
        Data="m101,51 l-100,0 a100,50 180 1 1 200,0" />
    <Path
        Stroke="Red"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Fill="MistyRose"
        Width="202"
        Height="102"
        Stretch="None"
        Data="m201,51 a100,50 180 0 1 -100,50 l0,-50" />
</Grid>
```